# creating a mapping variable in python

Tags: python

This is a little extension to my previous problem. I have a variable known as `region` with values such as:

```
/health/blood pressure
/health/diabetes
/cmd/diagnosis
/fitness
/health
/health/type1 diabetes
```

Now I want to add one more variable known as `region_map` alongside with `region` variable which maps each region to a unique name such as `Region1`, `Region2`, so on as they appear sequentially in the column. So the output would look like:

```
/health/blood pressure        Region1
/health/diabetes              Region2
/cmd/diagnosis                Region3
/fitness                      Region4
/health                       Region5
/health/type1 diabetes        Region6
```

Also all the region values are unique.

Basically its a web related data, but not now its a stand alone task. In python shell I have imported the data which just consists of unique list of regions. Now first task was to remove the integer values, which I did successfully with the help of other members. Now I have around 2000+ entries for regions. Sample data as i mentioned above, you can see it. For subsequent analysis like merging it with other files, I want to add mapping variable to the existing column, which is region. So for each unique 2000+ entries I want separate mapping variable such as  region 1, region 2, region 3, region 2000+. I have created a dictionary with following code:

```
mapping={region:index for index, region in enumerate(data.region)}
```

But problem is how to loop through it and replacing existing values with region 1, region 2 and so on. Basically as i explained I want to add one more column with each entry mapping to different region. Hope this explains you well!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already have an array list of the regions and needs new array list with the mapping of REGION and REGION MAP.

```
region = ["/health/blood pressure", "/health/diabetes", "/cmd/diagnosis" ,"/fitness", "/health", "/health/type1 diabetes"]

region_mapped = {}
region_count = len(region)
for region_index in range(0, region_count):
    region_mapped[region[region_index]] = "Region-%s" % region_index

print(region_mapped)
```

As its available with LIST - DICT can not append/extend the elements.

As you will need key:value pair kind of elements then above example is best suited. Still you can make it even optimised by creating def.

Comment: The code above prints: {'/health/blood pressure': 'Region-0', '/health/type1 diabetes': 'Region-5', '/cmd/diagnosis': 'Region-2', '/health/diabetes': 'Region-1', '/health': 'Region-4', '/fitness': 'Region-3'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) so you will have keys as names and the regions as values.

You can use it like this:

> dict[key] = value

This will create a new key and assign a value for it.
You can put the key like this "/health/blood pressure" and then the value like this "Region 1".
When you refer to it:

> dict["/health/blood pressure"]

It will return "Region 1".

To loop through the dictionary, do the following:

```
for i in dictionary:
  # condition to see if you need to change the current value
  dictionary[i] = "New Value" # The I represents the key in the dictionary.
```

For more information look in the python manual, cause these are just basic information for using dictionaries, and if you are doing a web service personally I would prefer using a DB for this. But again I don't know the bigger picture so its hard to say.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I am using  dictionary comprehension but not able to figure out. The code I am using is:                 matches = {region: [i for i in data.region ] for region in data} This  gives me the dictionary with just values. What I am looking for is separate two columns as highlighted above.

Comment: Thanks for responding Yousuf . In actual I have 2000+ entries for region. Can you suggest some automated code which would assign all these regions a unique mapping variable. Also my target is to get a separate column beside the region variable as indicated in the sample output. Can we achieve that?

Comment: Maybe if you give me more info as to where you getting all the data from and what are you trying to do is this something that is connected to a web service is this standalone, I need more info.

Comment: I have edited the question by adding more detailed information in it. Hope this provides you the essential background.

Comment: Please look at the edit. Note that you asked two different questions in the same place, and that you are asking about very basic stuff...

Comment: I am new to python. So basic things are not trivial in the start. I mentioned about the first question so that you can have a clear idea. Yeah I already tried this way of looping through the dictionary. But are you sure through this we can get separate column?

Comment: Yes it will simulate two columns the 'keys' and the 'values' and you can use and change both of them...